# Embedded Login Use

Tags: login

I have found a new feature called [embedded login in Salesforce '17 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_security_id_embedded_login.htm). I'm not able to find more information about this feature nor can I find it in my developer sandbox.

How can I use this new feature?

EDIT:

I have found this feature well explained in [this document](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_external_identity_implementation_guide.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You might see login with facebook or login with LinkedIn now in salesforce community they can use social login or any other identity provider to authenticate them.

Enable users to log in before accessing a web page, such as your shopping cart, or your entire website with the Salesforce Identity Embedded Login feature. This feature is new in both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.

For this, you need to do below

1. set up a [community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=0)
2. set up identity provider.

I will be working on this and update steps once I am done. Thanks for posting this.